# Sending commands into FGDB

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, file-geodatabase, big-data, parallel-processing

I have a large `.gdb` of all blocks in the United States, [available from Census](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-geodatabases.html). I would like to create a point shape file of all census tract centroids in the US.

I have QGIS with FileGDB enabled, as well as R with `rgdal`, so reading the data is not a technical problem. My issue is that reading the layer into `R` has taken 2 hours and used up 56 Gb (I have 64) of memory, and it's not done. I know exactly what I want to do:

1. Create a tract field by pulling the first 7 characters out of the GEOID field
2. Dissolve the blocks on this field
3. Calculate the centroids of the new geographies
4. Export as a points shape file, or even as another layer in the database.

QGIS shows the data, but the field calculations take just about as long. It seems that I should be able to send these commands *into* the database rather than load the database and try to do it interactively. I might need some hand holding to do this, or at least good pointers to the right manuals.

On the other hand, is there a way to pull the database out in chunks? I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a 12-core machine, so parallelization is always a good option...

Comment: File geodatabase is *not* an RDBMS.  It's just a file format, so there is nothing to send commands "into".

Comment: Ah, this is good to know.